# counter also should be in italic in amsthm package

Tags: fonts, amsthm

In my document, I need some theorem heading in italic and some in bold face, I have using the below tag:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
{3pt}% Space above1
{3pt}% Space below1
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount2
{\itshape}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head3
{}%
\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\newtheoremstyle{bfnote}% name
{3pt}% Space above1
{3pt}% Space below1
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount2
{\bf}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head3
{}%
\theoremstyle{bfnote}
\newtheorem{trial}{Trial}
\begin{document}


\begin{test}
This is for test.
\end{test}


\begin{trial}
This is for test.
\end{trial}


\end{document}
```

For bold, counter also comes in boldface and for the italic, counter came as in roman font, but I need counter also in italic format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle` (cf. Sec, 4.3 of the `amsthm` documentation)

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
{3pt}% Space above1
{3pt}% Space below1
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount2
{\itshape}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head3
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}% THEOREM HEAD SPEC (IF EMPTY MEANS `NORMAL')
\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
```

[image]

By the way in your second example (the `bfnote`) you better replace `\bf`  by `\bfseries`.

**EDIT** I was puzzled as why the original approach did not work and I looked into the code of `amsthm`. If the ninth argument of `\newtheoremstyle` is not provided the theorem head defaults to `\thmhead@plain`, whose definition reads

```
\providecommand\@upn{\textup}
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
```

The presence of `\@upn` therefore forces the counter to be upright regardless of the theorem head font (sixth argument).

**EDIT 2** A better approach is to retain the complete original definition of `\thmhead@plain` except the bit with `\@upn`:

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
{3pt}% Space above1
{3pt}% Space below1
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount2
{\itshape}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head3
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }#2}%
 \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}% theorem head
\makeatother
```

The original answer would have failed if the theorem were called with an optional argument.

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Please upvote the post also

Comment: nice, especially since it affects numbers only in the heading.  numbers in the text of the theorem remain upright.  (not ams style, but a reasonable request.)